# Surround failing higher order function with try catch?

Tags: scala

Below code is throwing an exception :

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
> at line
> (s(0).toString,s(0).toString)
> ```

I would like to catch this exception and just continue the map function to the next item. How can I surround a try / catch around the higher order function in order to ignore any exceptions and continue with the rest of the functions : groupBy & mapValues ?

```
println(toIterate.toList.map(s => (s(0).toString,s(0).toString))
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .mapValues(_.map(_._2)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the `String` indexing in a `Try` . The `Try` will return `Success` or `Failure` as shown in the example below. You can then match on these values to compose the rest of the expression. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

```
scala> val f = "foo"
f: String = foo

scala> List(0,1,2,3,4).map(xs => Try(f(xs)))
res0: List[scala.util.Try[Char]] = List(Success(f), Success(o), Success(o), Failure(java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3), Failure(java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to filter out items where an exception would occur, you should use `filter`:

```scala
println(toIterate.toList
    .filter(_.length > 0)
    .map(s => (s(0).toString,s(0).toString))
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .mapValues(_.map(_._2)))
```

Comment: my main goal is to allow execution to continue even if an IndexOutOfBounds exception is thrown on any of the String elemens

Comment: This accomplishes the same thing, but by identifying cases where the exception would occur and skipping it.

Answer (score 0):

A google search for "try catch scala" will reveal some options if your questions is about the sytax of try and catch. But I think a more realistic answer would be to use and "if" condition at the point of pattern mapping (reference this excellent article) along with "Collect"

http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/12/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-4-pattern-matching-anonymous-functions.html#comment-975636567

something like this (sorry you may have to play with the syntax)

```
println(toIterate.toList.collect(case(s) if s.len>0).map( s => (s(0).toString,s(0).toString)) .groupBy(_._1) .mapValues(_.map(_._2)))
```